# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an insert stored procedure like this

```
  if exists(select EmailId from Profile_Master where EmailId=@EmailId)
set @result=-1
else
begin
set @result=0


 insert into Profile_Master(FirstName,LastName,Dob,Gender,MobileNo,Country,State,EmailId,Password)
 values 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Dob,@Gender,@MobileNo,@Country,@State,@EmailId,@Password)
set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
return
end 

 pid = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
            pid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int res = Convert.ToInt32(pid.Value);
```

I am catching the value of last inserted record but i am getting an error like

Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.How to catch the value of last inserted record?

Comment: if you are expecting ID to come back with an identity value are you sure the table definition of Profile_Master actually includes an identity column?

Comment: userid column is the identity column in the table.

Comment: Are you sure? If @id is null then either a) the identity column isn't be populated or b) the stored procedure parameter list has forgotten to mark id as output. - You should edit and include the WHOLE sp definition, including the create line and the table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a null-check before you try to convert the value.

```cs
if( pid.Value is DBNull )
{
    // Do alternative route.
}
else
{
    int res = Convert.ToInt32(pid.Value);
}
```

or:

```
if( ! pid.Value is DBNull )
{
    int res = Convert.ToInt32(pid.Value);
}
```

Comment: pid is a sqlparameter and it says cannot apply operator ! to operand of type 'object'

Comment: You can use pid.Value == DBNull.Value

Comment: Now i cant return the value of res.

Answer (score 1):

Well, clearly we can assume that `pid.Value` is equal to `DBNull.Value` and cannot be converted to type `int`

You need to check what the sp does adn what it returns from the Database.

Comment: How can i check about what the SP returns?

Comment: What happens if you execute the SP straight against the Database? Which Database are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server 2005, i am checking for a duplicate email value and after that i am catching the last inserted record value.Updated the question.

Comment: And if you were to run the SP in Management Studio with the same values you run from C#, what is the return value? You need to focus on what the SP is returning, as it seems that the value is NULL.

Comment: How can i run SP in Management Studio??how to know the return value.